# How to publish a Unity desktop game without a security warning?

Tags: unity, windows, publishing

When I build a Unity game as a Windows Desktop application, zip the folder, and upload the zip to itch.io, then anyone downloading the zip from itch.io and running the game gets a security warning from Windows. 
Is there a way to build the game in a way that will not show this warning?

Comment: Is that an anti-virus warning? I published recently a game made with a custom engine, where it's guaranteed there is nothing malicious happening, and some anti-virus software would still flag it as dangerous. I doubt there is anything Unity-specific you can do, hopefully someone with more familiarity with the engine can confirm this.

Comment: You may be interested in [Signing a Windows Executable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252226/3064164). A signature verifies that the code is unmodified from a known author, making it look much less suspicious to anti-viruses and OS protections.

Comment: @TomTsagk It's not from an anti-virus - it is from Windows itself.

Comment: I would like to know the same...